# DNS name for an Oracle Cloud public IP

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

[image: Azure IP Configuration]

I cannot figure out how to provide a DNS name to an IP address in Oracle cloud. Did not find a documentation. Went through the portal settings and some CLI documentation around networking. But did not find any.

It is quite straightforward in Azure. As the above screenshot shows.

Can anyone point me in right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hostname you provide at instance creation along with the subnet domain name becomes the instance's fully qualified domain name (FQDN). You can find more details in this chapter of the documentation: [DNS in Your Virtual Cloud Network](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Concepts/dns.htm)

In case of the Load Balancer's public IP, you can associate the public IP address with a friendly DNS name through any DNS vendor. You may also create and manage your DNS Zones within OCI Domain Name System, but you still need to register your domain name at a 3rd party DNS vendor. For more details on OCI DNS service, please see the [DNS Service documentation](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/DNS/Concepts/dnszonemanagement.htm).

Comment: Thanks lsarecz.. i have to go back and look at it again. But here I am talking about a load balancer's IP address. Not a VM. If it makes a difference.

Comment: I see. My answer was about the VM, so I will add the Load Balancer aspects to it.

Comment: I have read *DNS in Your Virtual Cloud Network* several times and find no mention of Oracle providing DNS for a ***public*** IP address.  Rather this document has to do with ***private*** IP addresses by which OCI entities communicate with one another.  Further, if you run `host` or a similar utility on the public IP of an OCI instance you will find there is no DNS entry for it.  In this way OCI differs from AWS, which assigns a reverse DNS record to the public IP address of an instance.

Comment: But the loadbalancer public ip is dynamic. Right? I could not see the public dns name in Oracle loadbalancer.